# Magento XML sitemap

Tags: xml, magento, sitemap

Please excuse my ignorance to this but I am pretty new to magento. I am trying to create an XML sitemap for a website that has 3 store fronts. I have followed the steps to generate a sitemap and the sitemap has been created within the given folder, however when I open the sitemap's directory there seems to be a parse error. Can anyone help please?

This is what the generated file contains now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

Comment: Please add more information, if you can provide the link of the sitemap then it will be easier to anwer..regards

Comment: use google site map magento http://inchoo.net/magento/manual-creation-of-google-sitemap-in-magento/

Comment: That's not even a well-formed XML document: the `urlset` tag isn't closed.